# Displaying "string indices must be integers" on using Post On Session method

Tags: python, robotframework

When I am using the getting the response from below line, it displaying

`string indices must be integers`.

```
Create Session alias=mysession  url=http://connect.routee.net/sms cookies={}, auth=None, timeout=None, proxies=None, verify=False, debug=0
    
${data}= Create Dictionary  grant_type=client_credentials     client_id=610017f68ea04e0001850ac0  client_secret=54pEPyY68X
    
${headers}= Create Dictionary    Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded

${resp}= post on session     mysession/data=${data}       headers=${headers}
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's because of `cookies={}` which probably sets cookies to the two-byte string "{}" rather than an empty dictionary.

Comment: @DarkKnight: it's tangentially related; robot framework is written in python and uses python data structures such as dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have tried with below code snippet and I succeeded this time. But getting the response as 401. Can any help me please?
Create Session  hook     https://connect.routee.net/sms
${data}=    Create Dictionary   grant_type=client_credentials   client_id=610017f68ea04e0001850ac0      client_secret=54pEPyY68X        
${headers}=     Create Dictionary   Authorization=Bearer NjEwMDE3ZjY4ZWEwNGUwMDAxODUwYWMwOjU0cEVQeVk2OFg=   Content-Type=application/json
${resp}=    post request    hook    /   data=${data}    headers=${headers}
log to console  ${resp.status_code}